# How do i re-sign ipa file, Which is downloaded from App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

By Using this Script, resigned IPA File Which is Downloaded From AppStore, Launching in iphone Device But unable to open app When Clicked on App
it Opening and Closing (Like Flash Screen).

sign.sh

```cmd
# !/bin/bash
SOURCEIPA="$1"
DEVELOPER="$2"
MOBILEPROV="$3"
TARGET="$4"
BUNDLE="$5"

unzip -qo "$SOURCEIPA" -d extracted

APPLICATION=$(ls extracted/Payload/)

cp "$MOBILEPROV" "extracted/Payload/$APPLICATION/embedded.mobileprovision"

echo "Resigning with certificate: $DEVELOPER"
find -d extracted  \( -name "*.app" -o -name "*.appex" -o -name "*.framework" -o -name "*.dylib" \) > directories.txt
if [[ "$BUNDLE" != 'null.null' ]]; then
echo "Changing BundleID with : $BUNDLE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set:CFBundleIdentifier $BUNDLE" "extracted/Payload/$APPLICATION/Info.plist"
fi
security cms -D -i "extracted/Payload/$APPLICATION/embedded.mobileprovision" > t_entitlements_full.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c 'Print:Entitlements' t_entitlements_full.plist > t_entitlements.plist
#/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print:application-identifier' t_entitlements.plist > t_entitlements_application-identifier   #save developer application-identifier to file
#/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print:com.apple.developer.team-identifier' t_entitlements.plist > t_entitlements_com.apple.developer.team-identifier  #save com.apple.developer.team-identifier application-identifier to file
var=$((0))
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
#/usr/bin/codesign -d --entitlements :-  "$line" > t_entitlements_original.plist    #save original entitlements from the app
#/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c 'Import application-identifier t_entitlements_application-identifier' t_entitlements_original.plist #overwrite application-identifier
#/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c 'Import com.apple.developer.team-identifier t_entitlements_com.apple.developer.team-identifier' t_entitlements_original.plist #overwrite com.apple.developer.team-identifier
if [[ "$BUNDLE" != 'null.null' ]] && [[ "$line" == *".appex"* ]]; then
echo "Changing .appex BundleID with : $BUNDLE.extra$var"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set:CFBundleIdentifier $BUNDLE.extra$var" "$line/Info.plist"
var=$((var+1))
fi
/usr/bin/codesign --continue -f -s "$DEVELOPER" --entitlements "t_entitlements.plist"  "$line"
done < directories.txt

echo "Creating the Signed IPA"
cd extracted
zip -qry ../extracted.ipa *
cd ..
mv extracted.ipa "$TARGET"

rm -rf "extracted"
rm directories.txt
rm t_entitlements.plist
rm t_entitlements_full.plist
#rm t_entitlements_original.plist
#rm t_entitlements_application-identifier
#rm t_entitlements_com.apple.developer.team-identifier
```

you need Run the below script file using terminal in mac, by giving path of below file in terminal(`"/signall.sh"`)

> Note: That [provisional profile,Distribution Certificate,Ipa File](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/) and these two script shell file should be in same folder, so that it will internally execute all files.

signall.sh

```cmd
# !/bin/bash
signscript="<path of File sign.sh>"
ipasourcefolder="<path of Ipa File>"
ipadestfolder="<path of ipa destination file to store after Resign resign>"

developer1="iPhone Distribution certificate"
mobileprovision1="provision certificate path"

bundleid="null.null" #use null.null if you want to use the default app bundleid


cd $ipasourcefolder
find -d . -type f -name "*.ipa"> files.txt
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
filename=$(basename "$line" .ipa)
echo "Ipa: $filename"
#_dev1_______
output=$ipadestfolder$filename
output+=".ipa"
"$signscript" "$line" "$developer1" "$mobileprovision1" "$output" "$bundleid"
done < files.txt
rm files.txt
```

1. Is there any issue with above code, why my app is installing in device but unable to open?
2. Is the above approach is the right way to Resign `Ipa` File from Appstore?